# Generating a report after running a feature file using Runner.runFeature() method

Tags: karate

I want to generate a report using below code:

```
Map<String, Object> result = Runner.runFeature( "classpath:FeatureFiles/Post.feature", args, true);
```

In args I am passing the test data to the feature file

Also the `runFeature()` doesn't return any keys related to request and if the feature execution fails no keys are returned to the runner class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get a report this way. This method of running a test is only for those who want to call Karate from Java. Please use the "normal" methods to do "testing".

Comment: Is there any other way to pass data arguments at run time?I want to maintain feature file repository and choose the feature file to be run at runtime based on the data.

Comment: @PreranaVarsha and search the docs for this line: `If you want to dynamically and programmatically determine the tags and features to be included - the API also accepts List<String> as the path() and tags() methods arguments`